# Why get() method on laravel returns multiple when I use find()

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

Hi I wrote this line to get a specific post but when I use get() after find() it return about 30 posts althought I used find() method..
$post = Post::find(5) ---- works well
$post = Post::find(5)->get() --- !!! 30 posts 
I know get() returns multiple records but I hope when I use find() , it get me only one post. Can someone explain how it's working ?

Comment: if you want only one record you can try first() instead of get()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The get method returns the collection of the model in question.

If you do:

```
Post::find(1)->get();
```

You will get the collection of posts that the post of id 1 is related with.

If you do:

```
Post::find(30)->get()->find(1);
```

You will get the first post of that collection because the get method is returning the collection of posts that the post of id 30 is a part of.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `get()` with `find()`

```
Post::find(5) \\ return one post of Id: 5
```

whereas

```
Post::find(5)->get();
```

will work same as

```
Post::all()
```

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd won't return the same. `all()` returns every record in the table.

Answer (score 1):

```
If you use Post::find(1)
it find record that have id 1 and return only that object not collection

but if you use get() then it return collection

in this case

Post::find(1)->get();
it is getting single data with find(1) but after that it run get() so it get all collection of database.
if you want to know how you can simply try by using get() without using find
Post::get(); is equivalent to Post::find(1)->get() or any number

Post::find(1)->get() find(1) is useless here
```